# how to uninstall oracle database from Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, uninstall, oracle

i used this link to install `oracle database 12c se2`.
http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/11g/r1/prod/install/dbinst/dbinst.htm
i know that this link is 11g but i just used this steps.
now i need to uninstall it, what should i do ?
i tried to search about that but i can't find what first step and from where should i begain

Answer (score 8):

**Uninstall Oracle 11g XE on Linux Ubuntu**

The following will completely uninstall and remove Oracle 11g XE:
Open a terminal session and login as user root:

```
$ sudo su
```

Enter the following:

```
# /etc/init.d/oracle-xe stop
# dpkg --purge oracle-xe
# rm -r /u01/app
# rm /etc/default/oracle-xe

# update-rc.d -f oracle-xe remove
# update-rc.d -f oracle-mount remove
# update-rc.d -f oracle-shm remove
```

Source: https://community.oracle.com/thread/2303639

Answer (score 1):

- Stop all servers
- `rm -Rf $ORACLE_HOME`
- `sudo cd $ORACLE_BASE && rm -Rf admin doc jre o*`
- `rm /etc/oratab /etc/emtab`

And that should be it unless you added personal directories outside these locations.

Comment: i didn't open it
should i stop all servers too ?