# "bash: /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/nls_lang.sh: No such file or directory" message appears in terminal window

Tags: bash, oracle

I have uninstalled my Oracle 11g by following the first answer of [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/740203/how-to-uninstall-oracle-database-from-ubuntu-14-04). But after that whenever I open my terminal this following message is shown. How can I fix it and will it make any harm to my system?

```
bash: /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/nls_lang.sh: No such file or directory
```

Output of `cat ~/.bashrc`:

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# colored GCC warnings and errors
#export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe
export ORACLE_SID=XE
export NLS_LANG=`$ORACLE_HOME/bin/nls_lang.sh`
export ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`export` keyword is used for variables which would be used by other programs or the shell. Whenever terminal is launched it looks into `.bashrc` to determine the variables that can be used. If some errors are found in them, it simply reports/displays it. Although you've uninstalled Oracle 11g and deleted its files but somehow forgot to remove variables defined. To remove those variables

- Edit `.bashrc` using `sudo` privileges.

  ```
  sudo nano ~/.bashrc
  ```
- Remove lines 118 to 123 which starts with `export`.
- Save using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> followed by <kbd>Y</kbd>
- Reload `.bashrc` using

  ```
  . ~/.bashrc
  ```

  or

  ```
  source ~/.bashrc
  ```
- Open a new terminal to check whether errors are removed.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Edit `/etc/bash.bashrc`
2. Comment (starting with #) from

   ```
   # export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe
   # export ORACLE_SID=XE
   # export NLS_LANG=`$ORACLE_HOME/bin/nls_lang.sh`
   # export ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle
   # export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
   # export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH

   # and this one too
   # source ~/.bashrc
   ```

   then solved.

DO NOT FORGET TO COMMENT THE LAST ONE BECAUSE YOU MAY NOT BE ABLE TO LOGIN AS ROOT OR ANOTHER USER FROM CONSOLE OR XTERM.